Hacer un COUNT y SUM agrupado dentro de una misma tabla
Estoy con un problema al intentar incorporar un COUNT y un SUM de diferentes  registros dentro de una misma tabla. El resultado de un select sobre la tabla es el siguiente:



ID
Name
Age
ContactGroup




1
Carlos
48
1


2
Maria
45
3


3
Juan
55
2


4
Jose
43
3


5
Ricardo
38
1


6
Adriana
44
1



Lo que estoy necesitando es que el resultado sea el mismo, pero incorporar a la consulta dos campos que me muestren el resultado de un COUNT de la cantidad de registros de cada grupo de contacto y un SUM de las edades agrupadas en cada grupo de contacto. El resultado debería ser el siguiente:



ID
Name
Age
ContactGroup
SumAge
CountContact




1
Carlos
48
1
130
3


2
Maria
45
3
88
2


3
Juan
55
2
55
1


4
Jose
43
3
88
2


5
Ricardo
38
1
130
3


6
Adriana
44
1
130
3



Hay alguna forma de hacerlo? Intente varios formas, haciendo una subconsulta o haciendo un INNER JOIN sobre la misma tabla, pero no estoy encontrando la forma correcta. Agradezco mucho la ayuda que puedan darme.

Esto es relativamente simple de hacer con "window functions". Tendrías que agregar 2 expresiones a tu SELECT:
SELECT 
    ID,
    Name,
    Age,
    ContactGroup,
    SUM(Age) OVER(PARTITION BY ContactGroup) SumAge,
    COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY ContactGroup) CountContact
FROM dbo.Tabla
;


Muchas gracias!! Me sirvió, funciono perfectamente la consulta.
